# How can I add a lua/other languages to VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSC, all I can select is my Python Interpretter. I have Lua installed, same as Java, but I cannot run either, it will always run as Python 3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By it will always run as python 3.9, have you tried to make a new file, save as, and you can choose what type of language you are going to use. Hope this solves your problem!